# Xcode debugger not stop i ipod with IOS 5 Beta

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, ios5

I have 2 devices,iphone with 4.3.1 and ipod with 5.0.

The problem is that in my iphone the debugger stop in break points, and in ipod the debugger won't stop on break points.

Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: do you have breakpoints enabled when changing build configuration?

Comment: of course in the iphone device it work fine

Comment: your case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601265/iphone-dev-xcode-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints

Comment: is your iPhone device running iOS 5 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the iOS 5 SDK in your Mac? I think that is what you require.

Also you need to understand that some of the functionalities might still be missing in some of the cases as it is still a BETA version. It might not be a fully functional version yet.

So either you can try using the iOS 5 SDK in your mac or if you have already tried it then I think you should wait for the final iOS 5 full version to work properly.

Also in the below link, they have discussed that some of the functionalities of iOS 5 still doesn't work on iPod. So may be Apple is working on it before the final launch.

http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=344401

You can also try referring to this link:

[iPhone Dev: Xcode debugger does not stop on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601265/iphone-dev-xcode-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints)

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions, download lastest Xcode 4.2 beta with iOS 5 SDK, not working yet. I think I'll wait for the final iOS 5 full version to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the same problem like with iTunes. If you use a beta SDK you also need beta iTunes to sync with your device and a beta Xcode. Do you have the beta Xcode? Thats because the official Xcode release don't have an iOS 5 debugger. Open your Organizer and look if your iPod is listed as a supported debugging device.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have iOS5 SDK installed as well? Are you testing with that? If not, the app won't stop at breakpoints. Your XCode version does not have the iOS5 debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution to your problem, but I faced the same problem and solved it using UIAlertViews & NSLogs. I should also mention that I even installed xcode with iOS 5 SDK beta, even after which the breakpoints won't hit.

It was some issue with the symbols. You can create & display a temporary alert view where you want to put the break-point with its message/title being the value that you want to see, or you can log the value.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a device running iOS 5 you will need to install the beta version of XCode, which contains the iOS 5 SDK. Once you register as an apple developer you can download it from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).