# unable to debug on xcode 3.2.5 with ipod touch ios 5.0.1?

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios5

I have iPod touch 4th generation and XCode 3.2.5. But whenever I use build and debug the xcode never stops on breakpoints. Does someone knows how to solve this issue? The first time I connect the xcode organizer collects symbols. In my system this has done without hassle. Still I'm unable to debug. By the way I have two xcode in my mac one is 4.2 installed in another directory.

Comment: were you able to find solution ?

Comment: @ Jennis No Tried everything but still no luck.

Comment: Can you show the messages you see in your console when launching the app on the device?

Comment: @Dawood I have tried everything But now I have jaibroken my iPod and Now it even won't run apps. The xcode shows exited with status 45. Also I have xcode 4.2 and ios 5.0.1 in my iPod Touch

Comment: @RahulVyas are you able to debug with iOS5 , if so plz let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Do any of these posts resolve your problem?

[Xcode 4.2 can't debug iOS 4.2.1 (8C148)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838154/xcode-4-2-cant-debug-ios-4-2-1-8c148)
[iPhone Dev: Xcode debugger does not stop on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601265/iphone-dev-xcode-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints)

Comment: Here we are specific to Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 5.0.1 debugging requirement. Those questions doesn't relates to this !

Comment: As some of those solutions point out, this problem doesn't necessarily have to relate to the XCode and iOS versions. Also, it would be useful to have some console output or error/warning messages.

Comment: There is no output in console error/warning. Just it doesn't stops at debug points. We we have put NSLog statement at break points it prints so code is executed without problem except doesn't stops at breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the "Rebuild Code Sense Index" button under the "Project->Edit Project Settings" menu item?

Comment: I don't see rebuild code sense index option.. It just opens project settings menu where I can set profile and other compiler/linker settings.