# Xcode 6, breakpoints stopping in main, but not included files

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

All breakpoints in my project used to work fine. Now only breakpoints in main.cpp will stop.

Things I have tried based on many similar threads:

- Ensured the breakpoints are activated and appear in the breakpoint manager tab
- Ensured I am building for Debug configuration in Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme
- Ensured GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL is 0
- Unchecked Debug>Workflow>Always Show Disassembly
- Changed MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 10.10 and SDKROOT to macosx10.10, the same as the active SDK given by "xcrun --show-sdk-path" ([iPhone Dev: Xcode debugger does not stop on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601265/iphone-dev-xcode-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints))
- Created ~/.lldbinit and added line "settings set target.inline-breakpoint-strategy always" (http://lldb.llvm.org/troubleshooting.html) and confirmed that breakpoints in included files do indeed stop when using LLDB from the command line.
- Trashed ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
- Trashed project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata
- Created new Xcode project, cleaned, re-built
- Selected Preferences>Locations>Advanced>Build Location>Legacy
- Installed previous Xcode release (6.3) and switched to it with xcode-select
- Restarted machine

Could this have something to do with relative path names?

Output of `make`:

`mpicxx -g -v -m64 -Wall -Werror main.o -o main -lblas -llapack
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o main -L/opt/local/lib/openmpi-mp main.o -lblas -llapack -flat_namespace -lmpi_cxx -lmpi -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a`

Xcode 6.4 (6E35b), Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E46)